# numberOfRowsInSection called multiple times but cellForRowAtIndexPath never called

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I am tracking my code using NSLog at every minute state. For whatever reason numberOfRowsInSection is being called in an endless look, returning 1 correctly; but cellForRowAtIndexPath is never called. Any ideas what might cause this?

My table and the ViewController are laid out entirely using storyboard. This is the first time I am encountering this problem. Normally whether I use magic numbers or not, if numberOfRowsInSection is called then cellForRowAtIndexPath will be called. Why not this time? `[self.tableView reloadData];` is supposed to trigger them both.

Comment: make sure that you have linked your table view and table cell with correct cell identifier. If you have normal VC with inserted table view you have to link it in your storyboard with your VC.h

Comment: Update ur question with code

Comment: Check for delegate connection may be that cause problem or check for array count.

Comment: add the code snippet

Comment: Your array with which you want to populate table view might be empty

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to set the TableView's DataSource.